# MYSQL - INNER JOIN that returns an array of rows

Tags: php, mysql

Is it applicable to select all employee departments and related jobs *(including all data for all departments and jobs)* in one SQL statement where is every employee may be associated to multiple departments and jobs like below

Employees Table

```
+-------------+---------------+
| Employee ID | Employee Name |
+-------------+---------------+
| 27          | Name          |
| 28          | Name 2        |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Employee Jobs

```
+-------------+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| Employee ID | Department ID | Job ID | From      | To        |
+-------------+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 27          | 1             | 3      | some date | some date |
| 27          | 2             | 7      | some date | some date |
+-------------+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Department

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| Department ID | Department Name |
+---------------+-----------------+
| 1             | Sales           |
| 2             | Operation       |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

Jobs

```
+--------+---------------+-------------------+
| Job ID | Department ID | Job Name          |
+--------+---------------+-------------------+
| 3      | 1             | Sales Director    |
| 7      | 2             | Technical Support |
+--------+---------------+-------------------+
```

EDITED: 
Below is an example of the data I would like to retrive:

```
array(
  '0' => array(
        'department name' => 'name',
        'department ID' => 'id',
        'job name' => 'name',
        'job id' => 'id',
     ),
  '1' => array(
        'department name' => 'name2',
        'department ID' => 'id2',
        'job name' => 'name2',
        'job id' => 'id2',
     )
)
```

EDITED:

Here is the statement I wrote to get the array, but it doesn't retrieve departments data as an array

```
SELECT * FROM employees_emp 
INNER JOIN job_history_jhis ON (employeeId_emp = employeeId_jHis)
INNER JOIN departments_dep ON (departmentId_jHis = departmentId_dep)
INNER JOIN jobs_job ON (jobId_jHis = jobId_job)
WHERE employeeId_emp = '27'
```

Comment: If you mean, is it possible, yes it is.  If you have any control over the schema, it seems you can remove the `Department ID` column from the `Jobs` table as it already is there in the `Employee Jobs` table.  Do you have a specific query you need help with?

Comment: Yes. That's entirely possible.

Comment: It would be great if there is an example :)

Comment: That's not how this site works. YOU try to write the solution, and if you can't get it working you post your attempt, and then we show you where you went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: What are your expected results from this?

Comment: You also need to explain more clearly what you're trying to accomplish. Show an example of the result you're trying to get.

Comment: Based on your title, I'm not sure what you're looking for that's no different than the `EmployeeJobs` table?

Comment: I edited the question with the array I would like to return

Comment: Is your question about how to write the SQL query, or how to get the results into an array? PDO and MySQLi both have `fetchall` methods that return all the results of a query in an array.

Comment: I updated the question with my try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the values you are looking for, you can just join all of your tables together on the related columns like the primary and foreign keys, and include whatever you need in your select statement. Start from the bottom and build your way up.

For example, each `job` has a department, so you can get the info from those two like this:

```
SELECT j.id, j.jobName, d.id, d.departmentName
FROM jobs j
JOIN department d ON d.id = j.department;
```

To get the employees info, you can do the same by joining the `EmployeeJobs` and `Employee` table.

I would like to point out that you have some normalization concerns. In the `job` table you specify the department the job belongs to, there is no need to have `department` inside of `employeeJobs` as well, as you could experience some anomalies in your database.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT e.*, ej.*, j.`Job Name`, d.`Department Name`
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN `Employee Jobs` ej
ON e.`Employee ID` = ej.`Employee ID`
LEFT JOIN jobs j
ON j.`Job ID` = ej.`job ID`
LEFT JOIN Department d
ON d.`Department ID` = ej.`Department ID`
```